# Unable to resolve DNS in Azure Linux App Services

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-dns, azure-ase

I have a very exceptional situation that when I create an app service instance of type windows, the DNS resolution is working. I can do a nslookup or curl.

However, when I create an app service instance of type Linux, the DNS resolution is not working. I cannot do nslookup nor I can do curl.

The SSH shows me that /etc/resolv.conf is set to 127.0.0.11.

Where should I start looking at the root cause here ?

Comment: Have to migrated from instance type windows to Linux ?

Comment: Please refer [resolv.conf](https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/issues/410#issuecomment-460515706)